# Grabbing values from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, idioms

Is there a standard way to get values from nested dictionaries? The function is relatively easy to write, but I'm curious if there is something already in PSL or language itself that could be used in such way?

Here's example of what I mean:

```
def grab_from_dict(d, *keys):
    assert isinstance(d, dict), 'd must be of type dict'

    current_dict = d
    for key in keys[0 : -1]:
        if key not in current_dict:
            return None

        current_dict = current_dict[key]

    if current_dict is None:
        return None

    return current_dict.get(keys[-1], None)

d = {
    'a' : {
        'b' : {
           'c1' : {
                'd' : 'leeloo'
            },
           'c2' : {
                'd' : None
            },
           'c3' : {
                'e' : None
            },
            'c4' : None
        }
    }
}

print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c1')
> {'d': 'leeloo'}
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c1', 'd')
> leeloo
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c2')
> {'d': None}
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c2', 'd')
> None
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c3')
> {'e': None}
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c3', 'd')
> None
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c4')
> None
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c4', 'd')
> None
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c5')
> None
print grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c5', 'd')
> None
```

This gives me a way to get a value deep in a nested dictionaries without worrying about existence of parent dictionaries. So instead of writing this:

```
value = None
if 'a' in d and d['a'] not None:
    if 'b' in d['a'] and d['a']['b'] is not None:
        if 'c1' in d['a']['b'] and d['a']['b']['c1'] is not None:
            value = d['a']['b']['c1'].get('d', None)
print value
> leeloo
```

I can write this:

```
value = grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'b', 'c1', 'd')
print value
> leeloo
```

If any parent is missing, the function simply returns None:

```
value = grab_from_dict(d, 'a', 'a', 'c1', 'd')
print value
> None
```

Comment: Well, that would just be `d['a']['b']['c1']`. There isn't really a need for a function there...

Comment: `reduce(dict.get, keys, the_dict)`. (in python3 you have to `from functools import reduce`). For missing keys you might want to provide a better first argument that doesn't raise an error (not tested: `lambda d, key: d.get(key) if d is not None else None`)

Comment: No need for a function, unless you want error checking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Catching the exception should work:

```
try:
    result = d['a']['b']['c1']
except KeyError:
    result = None
```

Comment: Although I agree this will work, I would like to express without exceptions for situation which is pretty common in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could write/find a custom container class written with this sort of behavior (maybe is has a NoneDict object that returns itself if you try to get a key?), but perhaps the more elegant solution is a try/except block:

```
try:
    x = d['a']['b']['c5']['d']
except KeyError:
    x = None
```

since this is really just telling the program how to handle an expected error.  I would call that little code block the "pythonic" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for a function? Doesn't this cover what you're looking for?

```
>>> d['a']['b']['c1']
{'d': 'leeloo'}
>>> d['a']['b']['c1']['d']
'leeloo'
```

Comment: I added additional example that clarifies motivation for my question.